# Is there documentation to implement Zooz in a Codenameone Project (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, codenameone, zooz

I am trying to implement zooz in my codenameone project in Eclipse. Zooz has an android application example that I downloaded but don't know how to integrate it to my codenameone project. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to integrate anything into the Codename One project.

Just define the build hints: `zooz.iosappId`, `zooz.andappId`, `zooz.sandbox` (true/false).

And that's it.

Comment: I've defined the build hints already, well not zooz.iosappId because I'm implementing only for android right now. Then, how zooz is triggered in my codename one app then?

Comment: Use the purchase API with manual payment. There is a sample of that in the kitchen sink demo